# Weird "for" instruction to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

So I have this weird code that I never seen anywhere else. But it works.

```
    {{each sizes}}
    ${endMark($data, sizes, ',')}
    <p>${$value.tam}</p>
    {{/each}
```

This little script will write a paragraph for all the arrays items. I never seen something like this before and I need to convert that array to php.

I've tried something like this:

```
    {{each sizes}}
    ${endMark($data, sizes, ',')}
    <?php $testee = "?> ${$value.tam} <?php "; $i++; ?>
    {{/each}
```

But it does not work!

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some template engine is processing that
something like
https://github.com/mardix/Handlebars

Comment: I will try to find something. Thanks. Any ideia how to get that array to php?